# How do I share video through WhatsApp?

Tags: whatsapp

I m am unable to share my personal videos through WhatsApp. Do I need to download any extra app to share my personal videos or photos on WhatsApp?

Comment: Can you explain, what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Please post the exact steps you take in order to share the video, and mention the steps that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If your personal video appears in the Gallery(called as Photos in Windows 8.1 Update), then you can share your videos through WhatsApp. Just go to your chat screen click on the attachment icon, select video button and then choose the video to be shared form Photos(Gallery).

Alternatively, follow the following step if the video is not visible at Photos(Gallery)

1. Open your WhatsApp and Switch to Files(File Manager).
2. Go to the location where video is present using File Manager(Files).
3. Long press on the video you want to share.
4. Click on Share, and a list of application/ways will be shown.
5. Select WhatsApp from that list.

Your video will be now be shared.

Edit : New version of Whatsapp have a option now, to directly share the video.